Question about UC Execution
Consider the following simple UC module, described via pseudocode:


Read input from environment, and save it to var
Send var to adversary
Send var to environment


If I understand correctly, this can be translated to valid ITM code for a machine.
My question is about how execution would work in this case? Specifically, what I understand so far is as follows:


Execution starts with the environment having control.
The environment sends a message to our module, after which our module gets control.
The module saves this message as var.
The module then sends the same message (var) to the adversary. Now the adversary gets control.


Now, my question is: what happens next? I think that the adversary can do three things:

Send a message to the environment
Send a message to our module again
Pause

Case 1: Sending a message to the environment
If I understand correctly, sending the same message to the environment is the worst the adversary can do (dummy adversary). Now the environment gets control. What can it do?. It can send a message to our module or it can send a message to the adversary. Now, our module 'is in the middle' of an operation. When the environment sends it a message, does it just get control and ignore the message? On the other hand, what happens when the adversary gets a message?
Case 2: Send a message to our module again
Here, the adversary sends (backdoor) input back to our module. What happens here? Does the module 'bounce' and ignore this message? Does it just continue executing and ignore the backdoor message?
Case 3: Pause
I think that this is almost the same as case1. The environment gets control back.

Strictly speaking, the environment and adversaries are not "parties" in the UC framework, in that they have special status. The module can't send messages directly to the environment or to the adversary (it can send messages to parties corrupted by the adversary, but it does not know which are corrupted). The question still makes sense in the case where the module sends two subsequent messages to different parties $P_1$ and $P_2$ and I see two possibilities to this situation.

After reading its input tape and copying the content to its internal tape, the module writes both $(\mathrm{var}, P_1)$ and $(\mathrm{var} , P_2)$ to its output tape. Message transmission in asynchronous in the UC framework, so when the module halts and the control returns to the environment, it can deliver those messages in any order.
After reading its input tape and copying the content to its internal tape, the module writes only $(\mathrm{var}, P_1)$ to its output tape. The next time it is activated, it ignores its input tape and writes $(\mathrm{var},P_2)$ to its output tape.

Note that ultimately, the environment controls if and how messages are delivered between parties. The environment's goal is to distinguish between the real and ideal executions, and it can supress or modify messages towards this goal. In this example, the environment sees the same thing from the module, but in either one or two activations, so it really doesn't matter for the security proof.

Doesn't the module have a backdoor tape? via which it can send a message to the adversary?

When the adversary corrupts a party, it has access to all the tapes (including internal) of this party and controls all future actions of this party.

I guess what I was really calling a 'module' is something like an ideal functionality / communication substrate in this case
